# PictureBox is cutting part of the image when it's landscape

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

So I work on this MDI forms application and I use picture box to show pictures chosen from openFileDialog. However today a user complained about the fact that if the picture is landscape (I made my test with 1920x1200) it really cuts the right end of the picture. Of course the width of the picture box is a lot smaller (440px) but still even for the image that I used for test it cut just a little bit. However this is not acceptable so I want to make the whole image fit the picturebox frame no matter how big it is.

Here is my code for showing the picture :

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "All files (*.jpg)|" + prefixFilter + "*.jpg";
            openFileDialog1.FileName = prefixFilter; 
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Select file";
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = DefaultOpenPath;
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    IsImageOpened = true;
                    selectedFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    selectedFileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;

                    using (var temp = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(temp);
                    }

                    int imageWidth = pictureBox1.Image.Width;
                    int picBoxWidth = pictureBox1.Width;

                    if (imageWidth != 0 && picBoxWidth > imageWidth)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Width = imageWidth;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Width = defaultPicBoxWidth;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                    IsImageOpened = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error loading image!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```

Here I play with the image width but for different purposes, I don't know if I can use this code or there is some standard way to deal with this problem.

Also my picturebox has `SizeMode - Zoom`.

P.S

This is the original pic :

[image: landscape image]

And this is how the picturebox cuts it at the right side (look for the bushes from the original image - they're gone)

[image: cut off image]

Comment: Create a new project, add a picturebox, and reproduce the problem. Then show the code here. If you can't reproduce it in a new project, then the problem is obviously somewhere else in your code / ui design (something may be covering the right side of the picturebox). This should not be happening, it should work fine with SizeMode Zoom which you are using.

Comment: Agreed...that shouldn't be possible with "Zoom" set.  Can you post some screenshots of the full image and how it is cut off?

Comment: Now you can see in the edited post what really happens.

Comment: [PictureBoxSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx).Zoom should work. The size of the image is increased or decreased **maintaining the size ratio**.

Comment: The simple explanation is that the PictureBox is bigger than the form.  Don't forget to turn its right and bottom Anchor on.

Comment: @Hans Passant in fact there is a lot of space outside the picture box, it's not even close to be the same size as the form. From what I could find out the size of the picturebox is 440x360px and when I use big pictures the box hides a little of them. I tried with resizing the image before giving it to the picturebox and it seems that if the picture is with 40px smaller than the picture box it's ok...does this make any sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set `PictureBoxSizeMode` of the `pictureBox` as:

```
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.pictureboxsizemode.aspx) for more detail.

Comment: It doesn't keep the aspect ratio and also - I tried anyway - again some part of the image was cut off.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but looking at the picture it really seems like the PictureBox is simply set to the default `SizeMode` of `Normal`:

> Normal - The image is placed in the upper-left corner of the
>   PictureBox. The image is clipped if it is larger than the PictureBox
>   it is contained in.

**Double check** and make sure the SizeMode is set to `Zoom` and that somehow you aren't changing this property via code.